# Is there any way to detect a mouseclick outside a user control?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, mouseevent

I'm creating a custom dropdown box, and I want to register when the mouse is clicked outside the dropdown box, in order to hide it. Is it possible to detect a click outside a control? or should I make some mechanism on the containing form and check for mouseclick when any dropdownbox is open?

[image: user control]

Comment: Could you not use a control's "Leave" event? This would be fired when your new control would lose focus, I think.

Comment: Detecting when the dropdown loses focus perhaps? What if you tab away from the control, you probably want to close/hide the dropdown at that point too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I finally understand that you only want it to close when the user *clicks* outside of it. In that case, the [`Leave` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx) should work just fine... For some reason, I got the impression you wanted it to close whenever they moved the mouse outside of your custom dropdown. The `Leave` event is raised whenever your control loses the focus, and if the user clicks on something else, it will certainly lose focus as the thing they clicked on gains the focus.

The documentation also says that this event cascades up and down the control chain as necessary:

> The `Enter` and `Leave` events are hierarchical and will cascade up and down the parent chain until the appropriate control is reached. For example, assume you have a Form with two GroupBox controls, and each GroupBox control has one TextBox control. When the caret is moved from one TextBox to the other, the `Leave` event is raised for the TextBox and GroupBox, and the `Enter` event is raised for the other GroupBox and TextBox.

Overriding your UserControl's `OnLeave` method is the best way to handle this:

```
protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
{
   // Call the base class
   base.OnLeave(e);

   // When this control loses the focus, close it
   this.Hide();
}
```

And then for testing purposes, I created a form that shows the drop-down UserControl on command:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   private UserControl1 customDropDown;

   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      // Create the user control
      customDropDown = new UserControl1();

      // Add it to the form's Controls collection
      Controls.Add(customDropDown);
      customDropDown.Hide();
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {         
      // Display the user control
      customDropDown.Show();
      customDropDown.BringToFront();   // display in front of other controls
      customDropDown.Select();         // make sure it gets the focus
   }
}
```

Everything works perfectly with the above code, *except* for one thing: if the user clicks on a blank area of the form, the UserControl doesn't close. Hmm, why not? Well, because the form itself doesn't want the focus. Only *controls* can get the focus, and we didn't click on a control. And because nothing else stole the focus, the `Leave` event never got raised, meaning that the UserControl didn't know it was supposed to close itself.

If you need the UserControl to close itself when the user clicks on a blank area in the form, you need some special case handling for that. Since you say that you're only concerned about *clicks*, you can just handle the `Click` event for the form, and set the focus to a different control:

```
protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
{
   // Call the base class
   base.OnClick(e);

   // See if our custom drop-down is visible
   if (customDropDown.Visible)
   {
      // Set the focus to a different control on the form,
      // which will force the drop-down to close
      this.SelectNextControl(customDropDown, true, true, true, true);
   }
}
```

Yes, this last part feels like a hack. The better solution, as others have mentioned, is to use the [`SetCapture` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646262.aspx) to instruct Windows to capture the mouse over your UserControl's window. The control's [`Capture` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.capture.aspx) provides an even simpler way to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I never wanted it to close when the mouse left the user control, one of the posters just suggested this as an alternate solution. I'm gonna try to implement your answer. If it works this will be perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you'll need to p/invoke [SetCapture()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646262.aspx) in order to receive click events that happen outside of your control.

But in your case, handling the [Leave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx) event, as @Martin suggests, should be sufficient.

**EDIT:** While looking for an usage example for `SetCapture()`, I came across the [Control.Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.capture.aspx) property, of which I was not aware. Using that property means you won't have to p/invoke anything, which is always a good thing in my book.

So, you'll have to set `Capture` to `true` when showing the dropdown, then determine if the mouse pointer lies inside the control in your click event handler and, if it doesn't, set `Capture` to `false` and close the dropdown.

**UPDATE:**
You can also use the [Control.Focused](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.focused) property to determine if the control has got or lost focus when using a keyboard or mouse instead of using the `Capture` with the same example provided in the MSDN Capture page.

Comment: I have other controls in the usercontrol, and when these are in focus the Leave event is fired for the usercontrol.

Comment: @Bildsoe, if I understand correctly, you want to leave the dropdown open when the user clicks on another control inside your user control, but close it if s/he clicks outside of your user control?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - The dropdown should also close when the user clicks a control inside my user control, but not when the user hovers another control inside.

Comment: @Bildsoe, the `Leave` event should not be raised if you only hover over another control. Do those controls forcibly take the focus on hover?

Comment: Bildsoe:  Sounds like you might be using control.mouseleave instead of control.leave.  The latter will only fire when another control is brought into focus - ie clicked.  The former fires when the mouse is no longer over the control.

Comment: @Martin, but... both of us provided a link to the proper event... :)

Comment: Do not underestimate the evilness of intellisense!

Comment: @Martin and Hamidi - Hehe.. yup somehow I used mouse.Leave which of course is not the right one :) - however this still isn't exactly what i want to accomplish. I want the click to be the one that performs the actions.

Comment: @Bildsoe, do you mean the dropdown should close when you click on one of its items? If that's the case, since you're obviously handling that click event, maybe you can add code that closes the dropdown to that handler?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - this works, but clicking outside the dropdown should close it. This does not work. And control.leave doesn't fire when i move the mouse so perhaps I should look into SetCapture()

Comment: The `Leave` event is suboptimal for this purpose. It doesn't always get raised when you want or expect it to. The WinForms controls always capture the mouse internally when they do things like this. `SetCapture` is an easy way of doing that. I've been reading the comment exchange, but somehow it's still not become clear enough to me *exactly* what @Bildsoe wants to accomplish, or I'd have posted a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I'm creating a simple dropdownlist control. When the user clicks it, it opens revealing a series of options. If the user clicks one of the options it is selected. This works. If the user clicks outside the dropdownlist it should close. I've built this as shown in the image i will include in two mins.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi/Cody Gray - Do you have an example of SetCapture in use?

Comment: Have you tried the method you proposed? It is a hack and there are way too many ways that the control will lose the mouse besides clicking outside. An example is clicking inside the control. The mouse down captures the mouse and the mouse up releases it!

Answer (score 2):

Handle the Form's `MouseDown` event, or override the Form's `OnMouseDown`
method:

```
enter code here
```

And then:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{

    if (!theListBox.Bounds.Contains(e.Location)) 
    {
        theListBox.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

The Contains method old `System.Drawing.Rectangle` can be used to indicate if
a point is contained inside a rectangle. The Bounds property of a Control is
the outer `Rectangle` defined by the edges of the Control. The Location
property of the `MouseEventArgs` is the Point relative to the Control which
received the `MouseDown` event. The Bounds property of a Control in a Form is
relative to the Form.

Comment: this doesn't really work as the form doesn't receive a click if you click on another control

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the leave event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx

Leave occurs when the input focus leaves the control.

Comment: But "normal" dropdown menus stay open and doesn't close until the mouse is clicked. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share this. It is probably not a good way of doing it that way, but looks like it works for drop down panel that closes on fake "MouseLeave", I tried to hide it on Panel MouseLeave but it does not work because moving from panel to button leaves the panel because the button is not the panel itself. Probably there is better way of doing this but I am sharing this because I used about 7 hours figuring out how to get it to work.  Thanks to @FTheGodfather

But it works only if the mouse moves on the form. If there is a panel this will not work.

```
    private void click_to_show_Panel_button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        item_panel1.Visible = true; //Menu Panel
    }



    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!item_panel1.Bounds.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            item_panel1.Visible = false; // Menu panel 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I've done this myself, and this is how I did it.

When the drop down is opened, register a click event on the control's parent form:

```
this.Form.Click += new EventHandler(CloseDropDown);
```

But this only takes you half the way. You probably want your drop down to close also when the current window gets deactivated. The most reliable way of detecting this has for me been through a timer that checks which window is currently active:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

and

```
var timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 100;
timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
{
    IntPtr f = GetForegroundWindow();
    if (this.Form == null || f != this.Form.Handle)
    {
        CloseDropDown();
    }
};
```

You should of course only let the timer run when the drop down is visible. Also, there's probably a few other events on the parent form you'd want to register when the drop down is opened:

```
this.Form.LocationChanged += new EventHandler(CloseDropDown);
this.Form.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(CloseDropDown);
```

Just don't forget to unregister all these events in the CloseDropDown method :)

EDIT:

I forgot, you should also register the Leave event on you control to see if another control gets activated/clicked:

```
this.Leave += new EventHandler(CloseDropDown);
```

I think I've got it now, this should cover all bases. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Hmm, no. Don't periodically poll for the current foreground window. That's definitely a misuse of the API. You have a perfectly good way to do exactly what's being asked here. It involves capturing the mouse. Look up `SetCapture`.

Comment: Great suggestion @Cody, I'll be sure to check it out should I ever need to update this control. I recommend you take a look at that yourself @Bildsoe. I'd also like to point out that I usually implement my drop down as a separate form, so you'd have to take that into account using the GetForegroundWindow approach.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Form, you can simply use `Deactivate` event just like this :

```
protected override void OnDeactivate(EventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: this handler related to other event but not mouseclick